# Why isn't my variable being set with SESSION variable?

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I am thinking this is a syntax issue but I have tried it a few different ways.  PHP 5.4.16 running on IIS 6 (these are not my choices).

I cannot get $usr to be set to $_SESSION['uid'].  I ran a dump right after setting it and I see the uid info for the session data but NULL for $usr.  Syntax wrong?  What do you think is going on?

```
function User_CustomValidate(&$usr, &$pwd) {
    session_start(); // Initialize Session data
    ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
    $appKey = "pwssssssssssssss";
    $safeurl =  'https://safe.ssssss.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=playbooks';
    // first call back after safe login - POST is set
    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['digest'])) 
    {
        $digest = $_POST["digest"];

        // set the session variables ...
        $_SESSION['usernames'] = $_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST["firstname"];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST["lastname"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST["email"];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST["uid"];

        // Needed for key
        $uid = $_POST["uid"];
        $time = $_POST["time"];

        // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
        // this sets $appKey and $safeurl
        $mykey = "".$uid.$time.$appKey;
        $mydigest = md5($mykey);
    }

    // session is not initialized as we never got the post above to set session vars
    // call now the safe login to get the post to set the session vars ...

    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || empty($_SESSION['uid']))
    {
        // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
        // this sets $appKey and $safeurl
        header("Location: ".$safeurl);
    }   
    $usr = $_SESSION['uid'];  
    var_dump($usr, $_SESSION['uid']);                    
    $this->setCurrentUserName($usr);
    return TRUE;                    
}
```

So var_dump shows $usr = NULL and $_SESSION['uid'] with proper employee ID passed by SSO.

Comment: There is a session started... What are you suggesting?

Comment: Find where it's going MIA

Comment: Edited the post.  The session_id() statement had nothing to do with problem.

Comment: How do I find where it is going?  I just made the statement the line above.

Comment: Hard to tell seeing just a function that is a portion of what could be many pages of code but for sure if when you initiate it there and access the given url it does not initiate it was either unset else where or went MIA by some other code.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of var_dump to give you a snapshot of the variables right there?  How could they be unset?

Comment: For example if at some point your code is trying to regenerate a new session to continue the work however let's say the session line is missing the session would be unset and passed as is. You could manually set the session `session_id($session_id);` but it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: If I set $usr = '55'; it keeps the $usr information all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your POST data is correct?  I think the issue may be, without seeing the surrounding code, that the code inside your if statements are not being executed.  You need to confirm that your POST variable "digest" is set.  Or for testing if before that if statement you set $_POST['digest'] and $_POST['uid'] then you will find i think that the var_dump will not be null.

```
function User_CustomValidate($usr, $pwd) {
    session_start(); // Initialize Session data
    ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
    $appKey = "pwssssssssssssss";
    $safeurl =  'https://safe.ssssss.com/login/sso/SSOService?app=playbooks';
    // first call back after safe login - POST is set

            $_POST['digest'] = 'test';
    $_POST['uid'] = 1234;

            if ($_POST && isset($_POST['digest'])) { 
        $digest = $_POST["digest"];

        // set the session variables ...
        $_SESSION['usernames'] = $_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST["firstname"];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST["lastname"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST["email"];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST["uid"];

        // Needed for key
        $uid = $_POST["uid"];
        $time = $_POST["time"];

        // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
        // this sets $appKey and $safeurl

        $mykey = "".$uid.$time.$appKey;
        $mydigest = md5($mykey);
    }

    // session is not initialized as we never got the post above to set session vars
    // call now the safe login to get the post to set the session vars ...

    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || empty($_SESSION['uid']))
    {

        // Read the property file with the key and URL so this won't go into the main code ...
        // this sets $appKey and $safeurl

        header("Location: ".$safeurl);
    }   

    $usr = $_SESSION['uid'];  
    var_dump($usr, $_SESSION['uid']);                    
    $this->setCurrentUserName($usr);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: So if $_POST['uid'] is NULL then you are saying I am turning the SESSION['uid'] to NULL?  I can see this but I don't understand why when I echo $_SESSION['uid'] then I get employee uid info...

Comment: I am guessing if this is the case then when I am echoing $_SESSION data then it is reading it from actual session and not code?

Comment: If $_POST['uid'] is null then your code will redirect the user to the safe url in the second if statement.  You must also make sure the $_POST['digets'] is set, that allows the code to enter the first if statement and set $_SESSION['uid']